# Use branching in TFS for 32 bit and 64 bit version of a software?

Tags: tfs, 64-bit, outlook-redemption

we are in the process of porting a 32bit application, which uses the Outlook Redemption DLL to a 64 bit version, since redemption has recently been released as a 64 bit version as well.
We'd like to maintain two versions of the application, one for 32 and one for 64 bit.
What is the best way to organize these projects under team foundation server source control?
Would I create a branch of the existing 32 bit version? Copying the whole project seems sub-optimal since it would duplicate all the business logic code.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use TFS for this.

Create a facade over your access to outlook, then just have a configuration switch that decides which one you use?